# How send a value from a variable in form ODOO to a variable in a tree

Tags: odoo-11

I have one variable in tree called cost_element.
I have one variable in form called cost_element_id.

I have different variable names because the cost_element_id is a droplist. How when the user insert a value in the form on cost_element_id it reflects to the cost_element variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The two variables are on the same model and they are viewed on different views, so `cost_element` is related to `cost_element_id.

Example:

```
cost_element_id = fields.Many2one(...)
cost_element = fields.Char(related="cost_element_id.name")
```